# DOM Exception 9 when inserting SVG element with Ember/Handlebars

Tags: svg, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a problem using Ember/Handlebars with SVG elements:

Controller:

```
display: function() {
  this.set('isDisplayed', true);
}
```

Template:

```
<button {{action display}}>Display</button>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  {{#if isDisplayed}}
    <text>Foo</text>
  {{/if}}
</svg>
```

When I click on the button, I get this error: `Uncaught Error: NotSupportedError: DOM Exception 9` (`ember.js:18709`: `Metamorph#htmlFunc` on the createContextualFragment line)

Is Ember/Handlebars correctly handling SVG ? What should I do to make this work ?

[EDIT] A little JSBin to see this in action: http://jsbin.com/onejec/2/edit

Comment: I've edited my answer, have a look. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Handling SVG is somewhat tricky if you want to rely on ember to render DOM elements for you.
But as a starting point you could consider creating a svg wrapper like this:

```
App.SVGView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'svg',
  attributeBindings: ['height', 'width', 'xmlns', 'version'],
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
  version: '1.1',
  render: function(buffer) {
    return buffer.push('<text x="20" y="20" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px">Foo!</text>');
  }
});
```

And then hook into the `render` method to inject your `text` tag.

This results in the following HTML markup:

```
<svg id="svg_view" class="ember-view" height="100" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <text x="20" y="20" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px">Foo!</text>
</svg>
```

Here also your working modified [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/onejec/11/edit).

**Edit**
If you need to `re-render` the view based on some properties that might change you could add an `observer` to the correspondent property and call `this.rerender()` inside that method, something like this:

```
App.SVGView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'svg',
  attributeBindings: ['height', 'width', 'xmlns', 'version'],
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
  version: '1.1',
  render: function(buffer) {
    return buffer.push('<text x="20" y="20" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px">Foo!</text>');
  },
  myProperty: 'This value might change',
  myPropertyChanged: function() {
    this.rerender();
  }.observes('myProperty')
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you able to do that if you have to observe multiple properties in the view? I want to have a SVG that is always rendered, but with some parts of it that are depending on properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the edit! That's a good temporary solution before there is SVG support in Ember, if there will be. I'd really like to have the power of the templates (with the rerender of only parts of the template when properties change)